# remove empty line after edit file in php

Tags: php

I'm creating a text sitemap for my site it looks like this:
sitemap.txt:

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/estate/showAll
https://example.com/estate/search
https://example.com/site/about
https://example.com/site/contact
https://example.com/post/show/41
https://example.com/post/show/42
https://example.com/post/show/43
```

when the user delete post 42 my sitemap should change to:

```
https://example.com/
https://example.com/estate/showAll
https://example.com/estate/search
https://example.com/site/about
https://example.com/site/contact
https://example.com/post/show/41
https://example.com/post/show/43
```

I tried these ways but they didn't work as expected:

```
$sitmap = file_get_contents('sitemap.txt');
$line   = 'https://example.com/post/show/42';
$sitmap =str_replace($line, '', $sitmap);
file_put_contents('sitemap.txt', $sitmap);
```

this code shows an empty line in sitemap.txt

```
$sitmap = file_get_contents('sitemap.txt');
$line   = 'https://example.com/post/show/42';
$sitmap =str_replace($line, '', $sitmap);
$sitmap =str_replace($line, chr(8), $sitmap);
file_put_contents('sitemap.txt', $sitmap);
```

chr(8) shows backspace character `BS` it doesn't remove empty newline.

**I have done it with below code, but I think it uses too much memory if sitemap.txt gets large**

```
$sitmap = file_get_contents('sitemap.txt');
$line   = 'https://example.com/posst/show/'. $id;
$sitmap = explode(PHP_EOL, $sitmap);

if ($key = array_search($line, $sitmap)) {
     unset($sitmap[$key]);
}
$sitmap = implode(PHP_EOL, $sitmap);

file_put_contents('sitemap.txt', $sitmap);
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Both methods load the file in memory. A better way might be to read line by line while checking if the url matches to discard or not and then write to a new file at the same time so you never read the whole file.

Comment: chr(8) is not LF, that would be chr(10). But why *keep* it all in a text file? Generate it at runtime from a database. Then maybe you may cache it to a text file. You *have* to know that the post belongs to user 42, so some mechanism to walk the site must be already be in place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just replace the line + newline character (`\n`) :

```
$line = 'https://example.com/post/show/'. $id;
$file = 'sitemap.txt';
file_put_contents($file, 
    str_replace("$line\n", '', file_get_contents($file))
);
```

As pointed by [Nigel Ren](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1213708/nigel-ren) (see comment below), `"$line\n"` should maybe replaced by `$line.PHP_EOL`.

This depends of how you're building your file.

Comment: Should probably use PHP_EOL as this is platform independent, also this might not work with the last entry if there isn't a trailing new line.

Comment: @NigelRen You're right. I'll add this in the anwser. Thanks!

Comment: thank @Syscall. I think its a simple and good method. I just moved PHP_EOL to begin of  $line, therefore, there will be no problem for the last line.